# Database notifications and screen refreshing

Tags: android, realm, android-context, android-broadcast

I'm trying to do the following:

When my Realm database is changed, I want to send an event to all registered screens (tabs) of my app.

My approach to this, as I'm new to Android, is to create a singleton containing realm listeners, and send a broadcast using `LocalBroadcastManager` at that moment.

My main issue here is that to send a broadcast I need a `Context`:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast()
```

However I realized storing the context as static in the Singleton is discouraged due to memory leaks.

This makes me unsure of the best approach to do this. What do you recommend?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you listening only some Entities ? What do you want to do when your database changes ?

Comment: I'd like to trigger refreshes only if it's necessary, so potentially only selected Entities, but I also like simplicity :D Database changes should refresh data list, or launch calculations. Performance can be an issue but I'll have to test.

Comment: You don't need to manually manage this with LocalBroadcastManager because Realm already lets you register listeners on RealmResults which tell you that the Realm database is changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Realm notifications on Realm objects or lists : https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#notifications

Realm also provides adapters to help you : https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters.

Here you have an example project : https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters/tree/master/example

With that you can refresh your lists or views, that's the true power of Realm.